# Issues on create Magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, php, module, javascript, extensions

I create a module for Magento 2 to add a custom javascript to the theme head but my custom js file is loaded in front off all javascript files and this come with the error:

`ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

[image]

I add my file here:

```
app/code/MyModule/Customjs/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js
```

I create `requirejs-config.js` file here

```
app/code/MyModule/Customjs/view/frontend/

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom: 'MyModule/Customjs/js/custom'
        }
    }
};
```

I add `app/code/MyModule/Customjs/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>
        <script src="MyModule/Customjs::js/custom.js"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you want to call above js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remove default.xml**, By declaring js in head you are calling your custom js before query loaded, So remove this code and call custom js from your custom template.

Try this code in **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'custom': 'MyModule/Customjs/js/custom'     
    },
    shim: {
            'custom': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
    }
};
```

**Use this code into your custom template to call your custom js**:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">       
    require([
        'jquery', 
        'custom'
    ], function($, Custom){
        $(function(){
        })
    });
</script>
```

Note: You need to set dependency for your Custom js with jquery.

Comment: Hi thanks but is the same like before, the custom file is in the same place, I mean in front of all js files

Comment: you need not to call this js file from `default.xml` instead of that you can use it in your custom template while you need  to call  your custom js.

Comment: can you help me a little? how I can call the phtml block in the default.xml file for my custom module?

Comment: no need to call default.xml file in your custom module. If you want to call your custom js you can place it in any your custom template file if you are using it

Comment: but I need this phtml file to be a part of my module, because I need to move it to other sites, for that I need to call this block

Comment: then you can use default.xml file in you `view/frontend/layout` but need not to declare your custom js in head section, Instead of that you can call js from your custom template. I gave you a code to call custom js using script tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass dependency for it to load jquery first.
please replace your requirejs-config.js file code with below one,

**app/code/MyModule/Customjs/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'custom': 'MyModule/Customjs/js/custom'
    },
    shim: {
        'custom': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

**Remove js declartion from default.xml file.**

You can call your js file in any page using below way,

```
<script>       
    require(['jquery','custom'], function($, custom){
        // call custom object code
    });
</script>
```

**Or if you want to call above file in all page you have to keep above script inside header.phtml file of module-theme folder.**

Run Deployment command to work successfully.

Deploy your content and check again.

Comment: thank you but it's the same, the custom.js is the same in the front off all files and with the same error

Comment: I have updated answer please update your code and run below command, php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: is the same, and the same error

Comment: could you please clear browser cache?

Comment: I use another browser, I clear the cache, and in chrome for example I have this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: you need to remove from app/code/MyModule/Customjs/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: Add above js content in your requirejs-config.js file and let me know

Comment: I just do what you say and if I remove js declartion from default.xml file my custom js file is not loaded anymore